# Change cell Back Color in Edit mode

Tags: winforms, datagridview

I want to change the back color of a cell in a `DataGridView` when it is being edited. All solutions I tried applies the color when I get out from the cell. Because I want users to type something and in the `Cell_Validating` event if the value does not pass rules then I color the  cell disallow user from getting out the cell. Following is the code I tried:

```
DataGridViewCellStyle CellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
dgvAddAssets.CurrentCell.Style = CellStyle;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option will be to create your own CustomDataGridView class which inherits from `DataGridView` class and override the appropriate methods like KeyDown, ProcessDialogKey etc.

Another option is using the following code, which is a bit tricky.
What it does is enforcing the user to insert valid data. If invalid value inserted, the current cell will be colored in red, and return to edit mode state.
In this example, let's assume the invalid value is `"InavlidValue"`.

First, add these fields (we need them to be shared between different events):

```
private bool colorCell = false;
private DataGridViewCell cell;
```

Add and attach these events:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    // Here we check for the invalid value, and store the cell position for later use
    if (e.FormattedValue.ToString() == "InvalidValue")
    {
        colorCell = true;
        cell = dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];
    }
}

private void dataGridView1_CellValidated(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    // When value is valid, change color back to normal
    dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Style.BackColor = Color.White;
}

private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // User inserted invalid value, color the cell and return to edit mode
    if (colorCell)
    {
        dataGridView1.CurrentCell = cell;
        dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
        dataGridView1.BeginEdit(true);
        colorCell = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I am doing `e.Cancel = true` if validation failed. So the user won't be able to get out of the cell thus, `Selection_Changed` event will not be hit.

Comment: In my example it will also get back to edit mode, so the effect is the same as e.Cancel = true.
Give it a try, I think it's what you are looking for.

Comment: You were right. Your solution does work but not completely. Because the cursor forwards to the next cell and does not stay on the cell that was marked as red.

Comment: Are you sure you attached all the events as mentioned above? For me it works perfectly and the cursor remains in the current edited cell.
Make sure you update the `cell` field as in `dataGridView1_CellValidating`

Comment: Yes. I created a new project just for testing and it does shift to the next cell thus, not behaving like `e.Cancel = true`

Comment: Are you using TAB to go to the next cell?

Comment: I just noticed that for some reason it doesn't work with TAB (I tried with ENTER and arrow keys and it was fine).
I guess the best approach will be to create your own DGV class and override `ProcessDialogKey`.

Answer (score 0):

you can do change the edit text box's background color by doing

```
dgvAddAssets.EditingControl.BackColor = Color::Red;
dgvAddAssets.EditingPanel.BackColor = Color::Red;
```

these two lines will turn the box being edited Red BUT once done editing the cell will be it's previous color, as this is the editing Controls are entirely separate controls from the DataGridViewCell. 
I put this inside the CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged, and when you leave editing the cell goes back to previous color, and if you go to another cell for editing it wont be red, as these controls appear to be reset upon entering edit (but I'm not 100% sure)

Answer (score 0):

Just addressing the colour part of your question, you can use the EditingControlShowing event of the DGV and apply the style you want to the CellStyle in the event args...

This is a snippet from my code...

In the constructor I have

```
dgv.EditingControlShowing += dgv_EditingControlShowing
```

and then in the event I have

```
private void dgv_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(37, 86, 95);
    e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
}
```